# Passing objects between classes in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I'm new to Java and I am doing a homework on constructing Decision Trees. After 2 days of continuous coding, I finally built the tree and verified it manually. But I'm stuck on validating the tree, because, everytime I try to pass the "node" object to the Validator class, it is null. I tried all sorts of previous suggestions and nothing seems to work. I need someone to point out my mistake and why its a mistake. Here is a short portion of the code that will explain what I'm trying to achieve.
Please advice on how I should go about this.

```
//Node Class to represent a node in the tree
public class DecisionTreeNode 
{
    String attribute;
    boolean isLeaf;
    DecisionTreeBranch[] branches; //Another class to represent branch from a node

    //Default constructor for a Node: With attributes, label and isLeaf condition
    public DecisionTreeNode(String attribute) 
    {
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.isLeaf = true;
    }
        ............
}

//Tree class with logic to build the tree
public class BuildDecisionTree 
{
    public PrepareFile config; //Need this object to get a arraylist of values to construct the tree
    DecisionTreeNode root;
        BuildDecisionTree(PrepareFile config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }
    //Construct Decision Tree
    public void buildDecisionTree() 
    {
        root = myDecisionTreeAlgorithm(config.getExamples(), config.getAttributes());
        System.out.println("\n !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Decision tree was constructed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
        root.printDecisionTree("");
    }

//This is the validator where is want both the "config" and the "root" objects

import java.util.List;

public class DecisionTreeValidator 
{
    PrepareFile config;
    DecisionTreeNode node;
    BuildDecisionTree bTree;    
    public DecisionTreeValidator(BuildDecisionTree bTree, PrepareFile config)
    {
        this.bTree = bTree;
        this.node = bTree.root; //I tried adding a getter function in BuildDecisionTree class and returned the root, even then this was null. Like below
            //this.node = bTree.buildDecisionTree(); //made the return type of the buildDecisionTree function as "DecisionTreeNode"
        this.config = config;
        this.examples = config.getExamples();
    }
    public boolean validateSingleExample(Example example)
    {

        boolean result = true;
        while(node.isLeaf == false) //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
                ...........................
    }
}

//Main class
       public class PredictRestaurant 
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                PrepareFile config = new PrepareFile();
                BuildDecisionTree bTree = new BuildDecisionTree(config);
                DecisionTreeValidator validator = new DecisionTreeValidator(bTree, config);
                boolean isTrain = true;
                        config.setTreeParameters();
                        bTree.buildDecisionTree();
                }
       }
```

Comment: you need to post the text of the null pointer exception if you want constructive advice.

Comment: also since the BuildDecisionTree object is being passed into the DecisionTreeValidator it'd be helpful to show the code where you construct it... it looks like root is null until the constructor or BuildDecisionTree is called.

Comment: This is the Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DecisionTreeValidator.validateSingleExample(DecisionTreeValidator.java:49)
 at DecisionTreeValidator.validateDecisionTree(DecisionTreeValidator.java:28)
 at PredictRestaurant.main(PredictRestaurant.java:22)

The line which it points to is the one I have mentioned in code. The  last line in the code block.
while(node.isLeaf == false) //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Comment: building logic is the part of homework, which I dint feel comfortable posting. But, yes, the root is null until the buildDecisionTree.

Comment: In response to your comment on adding the buildDecisionTree method, you definitely need that method before the statement: this.node = bTree.root, otherwise bTree.root won't have been initialized and this.node will be null.  Thus, the problem likely lies in your buildDecisionTree method, and I suspect that your myDecisionTreeAlgorithm method is where the problem is.  Do you think you could post the code to the myDecisionTreeAlgorithm method?

Comment: Posted code for now, because I need this resolved badly. Will remove it once the question is answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. It wasnt related to the node being null. the node wasnt null.
when i traverse the tree and hit the leaf node, I was still checking for branches. corrected it now. Its working perfect. Thank you all for your recommendations. It helped me learn.

I will now remove the "logic" for tree building.

Answer (score 0):

Your node is null because the method signature for `buildDecisionTree()` is either `Object` or some other unspecified object; the method signature with `void` won't even compile.

You should change your method there to return an object of type `DecisionTreeNode`.

Comment: It was **never designed to be a getter method. so I made it void. But I tried making that as a getter method with return type "DecisionTreeNode" and returned the root, even then it was null.

Comment: Getters are **never** `void`.  As for why it would return null even when the type is set properly:  you'd want to look into what the return value for `myDecisionTreeAlgorithm()` results in.

Comment: @Makoto how does it compile? I didn't know you could "assign" the return value of a `void` method and make it compile... Is that because the return value is not explicitly stated?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Yeah, I'm not entirely sure either.  It may be that the return type isn't explicitly stated.  It absolutely refuses to compile.

Comment: @Makoto: return type of myDecisionTreeAlgorithm() is DecisionTreeNode and it has the expected value (the decision tree itself). Becos I try to do "root.printDecisionTree("");" which is a mtethod in the DecisionTreeNode and it print as expected

Comment: So...you'd be returning `root`, then.  Right?

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, I tried returning "root" from the buildDecisionTree() (after changing its return type), yet I get the tree as null in the Validation class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not initializing `bTree.node` properly.  In your `DecisionTreeValidator` constructor, directly after the line

```
this.bTree = bTree;
```

add the line

```
bTree.buildDecisionTree();
```

You did not have this line in your code, and thus `bTree.node` was defaulted to null as it wasn't initialized.  This made `this.node` null after the line

```
this.node = bTree.node;
```

resulting in a `null pointer exception` when you tried to reference `this.node` later on.
With this change, your code should work.  Tell me if you have any problems.